# Group messaging using an iPhone

Tags: messages, group

Is there a way to send group messages on the iPhone without an app? And without individually choosing the contact in the group?

Comment: What iPhone and iOS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone's built-in Messages app *can* send group messages: open the app, go to the messages list, hit the Compose Message button in the upper-right corner, and use the Add `(+)` icon in the To: field to add multiple recipients.

You cannot, however, add an entire group as a message recipient; multiple recipients must be added one at a time.